# User mapping error when updating FDW role

Tags: postgresql

I created a FDW a long time ago for `role1` with the following SQL, `role1` was the default admin account that is created by AWS Aurora:

```
    DROP SERVER IF EXISTS <server_name> CASCADE;
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

    CREATE SERVER IF NOT EXISTS <server_name>
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host <host>, dbname <db_name>, port <port>);

    CREATE USER MAPPING IF NOT EXISTS
        FOR role1
        SERVER <serevr_name>
        OPTIONS (USER role1, PASSWORD <password>);

    DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS <schema> CASCADE;
    CREATE SCHEMA <schema>;
    IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA <f_schema> FROM SERVER <server_name> INTO <schema>;
```

Now, I want to update the user mapping for the FDW to a different role so I am not using the default admin account any more.

I created a new role:

```
CREATE ROLE WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD <password>;
GRANT rds_superuser to role2;
```

Then I reran the above FDW SQL statements. Output of `SELECT * FROM pg_user_mappings;` shows the correct `srvname` and `usename`. When I try to execute any queries that require the FDW, I get the error: `user mapping not found for role1`.

If I recreate the FDW with `role1`, queries start working again.

Both `role1` and `role2` exist on the foreign server. The only difference I can spot is that when `role1` user mapping is created, `umoptions` contains the user and password in pg_user_mappings; `role2` has NULL for those options.

Also, I am using `role2` itself when executing all SQL statements. Using Postgres 14.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with `role2` that FDW are not working.

Comment: Your CREATE ROLE statement cannot be correct.  It is also not clear what user you were logged in as when each of these steps was run.

Comment: Can you reduce the number of redactions?  Why do you care if someone knows the name of FDW server, or schema, or port, or for that matter even hostname?  If security relies on those things being secret, then you don't actually have security.

Comment: @jjanes Posting hostname, database name and schema name is not a security problem, but rather a privacy problem for this StackOverflow account, as they may indicate their project affiliation. And who knows how serious their employer takes NDAs… But I agree they should be replaced by syntactically valid example values, not redacted.

Comment: You should add the statement you used to modify the user mapping to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, it doesn't matter who owns the server, schema, foreign tables, etc.  (If it did matter, you would be getting a different error, about permissions, not the error you report).

If you are logged in as role1 when the error is thrown, then the problem is self-explanatory and you are just overthinking it.  role1 uses the mapping for role1, and that mapping no longer exists because you dropped it when you cascaded the server drop.  It doesn't matter that the tables etc. are owned by role2.  I suspect that this is the case, as it explains your observation that "role2 has NULL for those [umoptions] options.".  If you're are logged in as role1 (being not a real superuser), it makes you would not be allowed to see role2's umoptions.

If you are logged in as role2 when the error specifically mentioning role1 is thrown, then you have some kind of delegation going on.  The simplest explanation would be a view created by role1 over foreign tables (regardless of who owns those foreign tables).  Now when role2 selects from that view, it takes on the persona of role1, including the attempted use of the mapping for role1.

The remaining option would be that AWS mucked things up when they forked PostgreSQL into Aurora.  I doubt that has occurred in this case though.